# intellisense in eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellisense

I use Eclipse

Version: 3.4.2
Build id: M20090211-1700
The problem I have is that when i use intellisense the error pops out

Problems During Content Assist
The org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java.TypeCompletionProposalComputer' plug-in did not complete normally. The execution took too long to return from computeContextInformation() operation

Is there a fix for it?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting this on a regular basis ? If so, do you see anything unusual in the eclipse logfile ? (workspace_folder/.metadata/.log file)

Comment: have you tried the latest eclipse version? Should be 3.5.1 something

Comment: +1, to above; your version is over 1 year old now. The first to do is to check the latest version (Eclipse Helios; Eclipse CDT 7 at least).

Comment: thanks I updated my eclipse to Eclipse Helios (3.6.1). Let's see how that will work

Answer (score 1):

Check, in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced if there is any unusual item checked. Only let Java and Template proposals checked and apply... Maybe it could be 'cause of one of the other code completion tools.